How do I delete a Sharepoint List from C# code?
How do I delete a Sharepoint List from C# code?
As I understand it, this seems to involve understanding the fact that we are dealing with one of two possible namespaces.  One is for the client side and one is for the server side.

Namespace: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client -- API: Client-Side Object Model (CSOM)
Namespace: Microsoft.SharePoint -- API: Server-Side Object Model (SSOM)

My code resides on the client side. It is also modeled after the example code found on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#using-modern-authentication-with-csom-for-net-standard
Here is the question. How do I programmatically, in C# delete a SharePoint list?  The authentication is not the issue.  I have already been able to create a SharePoint List from scratch, add columns to the SharePoint List, and I have been able to load data into the rows.  I think it would be helpful if I have the ability, if I decide that regeneration of the list completely is necessary, to delete the list.
Now, here is the problem I am facing, the following code:
                    newList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
                    
                    newList.DeleteObject();

                    context.ExecuteQuery();

Throws a peculiar Exception where I am told that "A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site.  Please choose another title."
So the execution query call on the context after a delete command is performed on the SharePoint List causes an error where it says that it can not be done because the list exists?!
Please advise.

Does newList contain the list object?  Are you doing anything else with context before you attempt to delete?  Because the code you have looks correct according to MS Learn. I suspect you have something else going on that isn't reflected in your code segment.

or: Deleting a SharePoint List
